# Is there a method to allow pure c file to use <Metal/Metah.h>?

Tags: metal

In other words, could ios's metal be used in pure c file? Thanks for reviewing.

Comment: `Metal` needs to talk to a `CAMetalLayer` (from the Core Animation framework) in order to render content in a view or a window. At the moment you can only do that using either `Objective-C` or `Swift`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Metal API is Objective-C, however that shouldn't present a problem as you can provide C functions within Objective-C implementation files so the rest of your C-based code can call these functions.

For example (I don't know the Metal API, so this is gibberish):

metalapi.h:

```
// This is a C function...
extern int doThingWithMetal(int someParam, const char *otherParam);
```

metalapi.m:

```
#import <Metal/Metal.h>

// ... implemented in Objective-C
int doThingWithMetal(int someParam, const char *otherParam)
{
    return [someMetalClass someMethod:someParam] == SOME_VALUE ? 0 : 1;
}
```

otherfile.c

```
#include "metalapi.h"

....

if (doThingWithMetal(1, "Hello") == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: In practice, it might look something like this: https://gist.github.com/warrenm/891d9aed154f142fc801

Comment: @warrenm Indeed; however I don't think the OP is very interested in the answer to his own question.

Comment: We shall see. I mostly wanted to share that sample for the sake of anyone who comes along later, as this isn't the first time I've seen this kind of question.

Comment: Thanks warrenm and Droppy.  I will try this.